# How to remove query from vue router?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

All the tries to remove query string fails

```
            // Initial state
            this.$router.replace({
                name: 'routeName',
                query: {
                    param: 123
                }
            });

            // Errors
            this.$router.replace({ query: {}});
            this.$router.replace({ query: undefined });
            this.$router.replace({ query: null });
```

How to remove query without any errors?

**Vue-router v3.1.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason `router.replace()` & `router.push()` need a non-empty object as query. So all rest to do is clean your initial query object from values, like:

```
let query = {
  param: [1, 2, 3]
};

// Initial state
this.$router.push({
  name: 'yourRouteName',
  query: query
});

// clean your initial query object
query.param = [];

// Now replace it
this.$router.replace({
  query: query
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**Vue 3**

This worked for me:

```
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'

// put this inside your setup() function:

const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()

if (route.query.username = 'test') {
  // do stuff...
  
  // clear the query
  router.replace({ query: {} })      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let query = Object.assign({}, this.$route.query);
delete query.param;
this.$router.replace({ query });
```