# Can not replace query string via Vue router

Tags: vue.js, query-string, router

I have a Vue app which needs to remove query parameter from url. Url looks like http://localhost:8080/campaigns/279707824dd21366?screenshot=1 Needs to remove screenshot param without redirect. So I found solution which looks like this:

```
    if( this.$route.query.screenshot ) {
        this.screenshot();
        const query = this.$route.query;
        delete query.screenshot;

        this.$router.replace({query: null}).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

This throws me an error without redirect:

> NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current
> location: "/campaigns/279707824dd21366?screenshot=1".

I also tried this:

```
    if( this.$route.query.screenshot ) {
        this.screenshot();
        const query = this.$route.query;
        query.screenshot = null;
        this.$router.replace({query});

    }
```

What is wrong with this code? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove query from vue router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840396/how-to-remove-query-from-vue-router)

Comment: I made an update. Look at the question. But still the same error.

Comment: you did the same thing again. try this. `this.$router.replace({query: {}})`

Comment: Does this answer help you? (use query instead of params)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687408/changing-a-parameter-in-vue-3-router

Comment: The first hint was the best. I did it this way: `this.$router.replace({name, params});` without query.

Comment: @MinSomai this.$router.replace({query: []}) works fine thanks.

Comment: @MinSomai I made a mistake in your comment and it seems you replace it according my mistake. The correct is `this.$router.replace({query: []})`