# Clear query params in Nuxt Auth on redirect

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt-auth

Query params aren't removed when user is being redirected to one of defined redirect paths (login, home, etc).

For example - user isn't logged in and tries to open some protected page `example.com/some-protected-page?test=query`. Then user will be redirected to login page. The full path will be `example.com/sign-in?test=query`, but i want it to be `example.com/sign-in` i.e. without query param.

I know i can implement a middleware to check routes and clear params if it's needed. But I'm wondering is there a more elegant way to do it.

Here is my config:

```js
  auth: {
    cookie: {
      options: {
        expires: 365,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      },
    },
    strategies: {
      sign_up: {
        scheme: 'local',
        token: {
          property: 'apiKey.accessToken',
          global: true,
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        },
        user: {
          property: '',
          autoFetch: true,
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/ActivateUser', method: 'post' },
          logout: { url: '/SignOut', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/GetCurrentUser', method: 'post' },
        },
      },
      local: {
        scheme: 'local',
        token: {
          property: 'apiKey.accessToken',
          global: true,
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        },
        user: {
          property: '',
          autoFetch: true,
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/SignIn', method: 'post' },
          logout: { url: '/SignOut', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/GetCurrentUser', method: 'post' },
        },
      },
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/sign-in',
      logout: '/sign-in',
      home: '/projects',
      callback: '/sign-in',
    },
    localStorage: false,
    resetOnError: true,
    fullPathRedirect: true,
    rewriteRedirects: false,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, using nuxt/auth. When I clicked on logout button I was redirected to login page, but keeping the query parameters from previous page. Like you, I wanted to have it clean.

The idea is to clean the query object from values.

```
this.$router.replace({ query: [] })
this.$auth.logout()
```

This clean the parameters and then redirect to login page.

For example: If the url we get is `https://myApp/hello?test=here` the `this.$router.replace({ query: [] })`, transform it to this `https://myApp/hello` and then nuxt/auth logs out and redirect to my login page.

You can check this answer related to vue-router from this post. I took it from here
[How to remove query from vue router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840396/how-to-remove-query-from-vue-router)

If user is trying to visit a protected page like you mentioned, I think the best way is to use middleware and not this way.

Hope this help!

Comment: To my mind it's not that elegant so far. I hoped to find some solution allows to avoid manual param clearance ($router.replace). But anyway your solution is robust and working so thank you for your help!

Comment: You are Welcome! The solution you are expecting, perhaps need to be implemented manually by someone, nuxt/auth team for example. But there will be times we need to keep those params betweens urls, and there will be times we don´t, like previous example. I think that something manually needs to be done to have these different cases anyway.